# Different versions of the apk for distribution

Tags: android, apk

It would be possible to have a project and with this (easily and without using if, for, switch case) generate different apks? For example, take an application for a client where X is configured icon, web services host, colors, and some code structures. And in this same design generate an apk with different data to a client Y and Z? Is there any easy way to manage these buildings apks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out build flavors for Gradle builds in Android Studio. I believe that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of using Branches in Git. Make a branch for each modification and generate desired APK

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible just change package name for other build(s).